# What would be Regex to match the following 10-digit numbers?

Tags: php, preg-match

What would be Regex to match the following 10-digit numbers:

```
0108889999 //can contain nothing except 10 digits 
011 8889999 //can contain a whitespace at that place
012 888 9999 //can contain two whitespaces like that
013-8889999 // can contain one dash
014-888-9999 // can contain two dashes
```

Comment: Jeff Atwood, one of the founders of this site, would strongly encourage you to invest in a copy of RegexBoddy: http://www.regexbuddy.com/

Comment: @BobKaufmann. The SO community OTOH would strongly encourage you to check out one of the [many open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regexbuddy%20open%20source) before.

Answer (score 5):

If you're just looking for the regex itself, try this:

```
^(\d{3}(\s|\-)?){2}\d{4}$
```

Put slightly more legibly:

```
^ # start at the beginning of the line (or input)
(
    \d{3} # find three digits
    (
        \s # followed by a space
        | # OR
        \- # a hyphen
    )? # neither of which might actually be there
){2} # do this twice,
\d{4} # then find four more digits
$ # finish at the end of the line (or input)
```

**EDIT:** Oops! The above was correct, but it was also too lenient. It would match things like `01088899996` (one too many characters) because it liked the first (or the last) 10 of them. Now it's more strict (I added the `^` and `$`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want a single regex to match any of these examples:

```
if (preg_match('/(\d{3})[ \-]?(\d{3})[ \-]?(\d{4})/', $value, $matches)) {
    $number = $matches[1] . $matches[2] . $matches[3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}/', $string);

0108889999   // true
011 8889999  // true
012 888 9999 // true
013-8889999  // true
014-888-9999 // true
```

To match the specific parts:

```
preg_match('/(\d{3})[\s-]?(\d{3})[\s-]?(\d{4}/)', $string, $matches);

echo $matches[1]; // first 3 numbers
echo $matches[2]; // next 3 numbers
echo $matches[3]; // next 4 numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pattern. It satisfies your requirements.

[0-9]{3}[-\s]?[0-9]{3}[-\s]?[0-9]{4}

Also, you can add more conditions to the last character by appending [\s.,]+: (phone# ending with space, dot or comma)

[0-9]{3}[-\s]?[0-9]{3}[-\s]?[0-9]{4}[\s.,]+